# how could I filter rows where any value in a pyspark column which is in array format is greater than 0?

Tags: arrays, pyspark, filter

For example,

I have a pyspark data frame like this:

```
value             
["9.1","0","0","-1.5","-3","9.456"]   
["9.456","4","5.345","6","7.34","8"]
["7","4","5","6","7"]
["-1.66"]
["0"]
["-5","4","6"]
["9","4.567"]
```

The output should be:

```
value
    ["9.456","4","5.345","6","7.34","8"]
    ["7","4","5","6","7"]
    ["0"]
    ["9","4.567"]
```

The output should remove the rows where any of the array elements has a value less than 0.

I tried this: but, it didn't work:

```
is_greater = lambda x: x>0 == 0
df_new = df_previous.withColumn("value", filter(f.col("value"), is_greater))
```

Comment: Could you show error message, if any or show what you are getting and how it is different from what you expect?

Comment: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3722268516349346> in <module>
      1 is_greater = lambda x: x>0 == 0

Comment: Are you looking for filtering row if there are any negative numbers? 
like `df_new = df_previous.filter(f.array_min('value') >= 0)`?

`withColumn` is to add/update a column with a new value and it won't reduce the rows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.